# Showing crashed/terminated pod logs on Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash, kibana

I am currently working on the ELK setup for my Kubernetes clusters. I set up logging for all the pods and fortunately, it's working fine.

Now I want to push all terminated/crashed pod logs (which we get by describing but not as docker logs) as well to my Kibana instance.

I checked on my server for those logs, but they don't seem to be stored anywhere on my machine. (inside /var/log/)
maybe it's not enabled or I might not aware where to find them.

If these logs are available in a log file similar to the system log then I think it would be very easy to put them on Kibana.

It would be a great help if anyone can help me achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use kube-state-metrics by which you can get all pod related metrics. You can configure to your kube-state-metrics to connect elastic search. It will create an index for a different kind of metrics. Then you can easily use that index to display your charts/graphs in Kibana UI.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics

Comment: thanks @sounak
I did install metrics-beat and Kube-state-metrics on my cluster and tried to do exactly what you suggested. Now I can see stats like pod is ready or not, deployment is available or not, etc. which is good but not exactly solving my problem.  I want to get the reason behind the failure of a pod in kibana. As of now its only showing if pod is running or not but not the reason

Comment: You can generate/calculate a different kind of metrics from Kube-state-metrics. You can follow this https://blog.freshtracks.io/a-deep-dive-into-kubernetes-metrics-part-6-kube-state-metrics-14f4e7c8710b for a different kind calculation. For your purpose you can use kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason/kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason metric key to get the data. All other keys information available in   https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md.

Comment: thank you sounak. It worked. Instead of going with the raw metrics, I used the "event" metricset that comes along with metricbeat-kubernetes module.